# Use of using statement for getting dbcontext connection object

Tags: c#, dbcontext, using

I am working on a report and wanted to generate an excel file from data. I have created a stored procedure which returns multiple datasets and because I am using EF which only supports single dataset, I opted to use below code

```
using (var connection = mydbcontext.Database.Connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format(@"EXEC prDailyRouteReport 
                                 {0}",refId);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //reading data and fetch next result
    }
    connection.Close()
}
```

Now the issue is, when I need to call two separate reports within a single web request the connection variable returns empty connection string on the second report. but I didn't get the issue if I remove the using block.
I want to know why im getting empty connection string with using statement.

Comment: Do you really need EF for this? Can you just open `SqlConnection` and do good old `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement in c# can only be called when instantiating an object that implements the `IDisposable` interface, which means that the resultant instance can be disposed. This is what happens when code execution leaves the closing bracket of the `using` code block. The object instantiated within the `using` statement, in this case your `connection` variable, gets disposed, and any existing variable references will by trying to access a null reference unless it is reinstantiated first.

Additionally, you seem to be running into a threading issue where you are trying to perform operations on the same variable in different threads. The issue you are seeing is just a symptom of that. You need to address accessing your variables in multiple threads and you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause the `connection` is available only within the scope of the `using`. Just run the second report inside the `using`.

```
using (var connection = mydbcontext.Database.Connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format(@"EXEC prDailyRouteReport 
                                 {0}",refId);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //reading data and fetch next result
    }

    command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format(@"EXEC prDailyRouteReport2 
                                 {0}",refId);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //reading data and fetch next result
    }

    connection.Close()
}
```